# VSCode intellisense for CGAL header includes that have multiples subfolders

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I searched a lot (1 week) for correctly setting up intellisence on Visual Studio Code. Nothing works... Can anyone give an advice why CGAL is not found properly? I can build and run code without problems, but coding is really cumbersome with broken intellisence.

If someone use CGAL in VSCode please share you properties file.

I managed to set all the libraries I am using, but CGAL is somehow special.
Intellisence is missing for it. I tried even to include dozes of directories of each header include files, but still it is not recognized. Other libraries are found without issues.

My c_cpp_properties.json looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "browse": {
                "databaseFilename": "",
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "includePath": [
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/viewer/include/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/viewer/include/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/viewer/include/cdt/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/viewer/include/imgui/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/viewer/include/opengl/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/viewer/include/pipe/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/viewer/include/ply/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/viewer/include/stb/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/cdt/CDT/include/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/clipper_2/CPP/Clipper2Lib/include/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/imgui/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/imgui/backends/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/glfw/include/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/glad/include/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/glm/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/glm/glm/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/glm/glm/detail/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/glm/glm/ext/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/glm/glm/gtc/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/glm/glm/gtx/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/glm/glm/simd/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/assimp/include/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/wood/include/",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/cgal/include/CGAL/", //CGAL/
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/cgal/include/CGAL/**", //CGAL/
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/eigen/Eigen/**",
                "C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/boost/include/boost-1_78/" //boost/
            ],
            "name": "compas_wood_config",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Ninja\\ninja.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "compilerArgs": [
                ""
            ],
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because all your `#include <CGAL/.....>` start with `CGAL` use this directory in the `c_cpp_properties.json`

```
C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build/compas_wood/build/install/cgal/include/
```

Why have you installed the CGAL library **IN** your build directory?

The build directory should ONLY contain stuff that you can generate, compiled results.

Install the CGAL files in a place like `C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/API/CGAL`

Comment: Hi,

This works. Thank you. The reason to install like this is to be sure that the project works will all dependencies on other computers. Besides folder structure, why this is wrong by installing everything into build?

Comment: @PetrasVestartasEPFL you should be able to do a `rm -rf *` inside your build directory and still be able to create/compile the application/library. You should put `build` in your `.gitignore`, have a look at git sub modules. Don't put stuff from other repositories in your own repo. Are you sure that on all computers it is installed in `C:/IBOIS57/_Code/Software/CPP/CMAKE/super_build`, I'm sure not all your team mates use this directory